# how to escape ctl00_ prefix or fix site css

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Hello boys and girls;

i have publish a website which made Asp.net and publishing MS Server. my project on 4.0 and server also like that. after publish my site , site dont accept all my css class. beacuse;
server added prefix as ctl00_ to all id's . and then i added all css class names ctl00_ and some of them is working very well but

how can i fix/solve whatever.

i tried to add clientID="static/predictable/Auto/whatever" but didnt fix it.
yes, only have 1 masterpage and i cant fix it.

if you help me , i will be very very happy. thanks a lot

```
<pages>
        <controls >
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****************" />
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*****************" /></controls></pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing classes and IDs. ASP generates the ClientID, but you can still attach a `CssClass` to your elements.

For example

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="myClass" />
```

The ClientID will not be "MyTextBox" but the class attached to the element will still be "myClass"

```
.myClass {
  /* Styling */
}
```

Comment: well yeah , i understand what u wrote, yeah it should be like that but why it dont accept. only <asp:menu left. i compile my own Pc no problem but server dont accept! well still dont understand whats going on. yeah my assing like that